# Two Different Numbers of Votes Cast

Tags: support, voting, activity

On my activity impact page, it says I have cast 45 votes:

> [image]

However, when I click on the link, and go to my votes cast details, it says I have only cast 40 votes:

> [image]

Why is there a difference between the number of votes?

Comment: @gnat though it doesn't explain that the "votes" tab still doesn't until 10k.

Comment: Although the above questions are related to my question, I would not consider them duplicates.

Comment: @nicael votes tab doesn't show these after 10K either (I just checked this at other site where have 10K). FWIW [official explanation](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5445/31260) I've got a while ago suggests that it is done this way primarily for users under 10K: "that would mean showing you links to deleted posts - that would equate to giving you broken links on your profile which would be bad"

Comment: @gnat my mistake; check my answer edit though and see this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YJRSz.png

Comment: I've edited again, hope it reads better now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number in the impact box of activity page includes your votes on the posts that were deleted since you voted. The "votes" tab doesn't include deleted posts (so it does mean that 5 posts you voted on were later deleted) - unless you reach 10,000 reputation and can see deleted posts; but it only applies to **close/reopen, (un)deletion** votes, not to upvotes or downvotes.

Also maybe the votes in your "votes" tab aren't filtered by "all" - it could be the reason of it displaying less votes than impact box.

(Actually "votes">"all" also includes close, reopen, (un)deletion votes, but I assume you didn't cast them - certainly not close and reopen votes, otherwise the impact box would show *less* votes)

Comment: The first part of the answer answers my question. I was on the "all" filter. And I do not yet have enough rep to vote for close, reopen and undeletions.